# Need help filling in the details of proof of Jensen's Inequality

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, integral-inequality

In a book on PDEs that I'm reading, I am trying to fill in the details of the proof of Jensen's Theorem, and am having a little trouble with the algebra.

Here is the statement of Jensen's Theorem in the book:

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}^{m}\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open, bounded. Let $\mathbf{u}:U\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be summable. Then, 
$f\left(\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dx\right) \leq \oint_{U}f(\mathbf{u})dx$

(In this case, though, $\oint$ is not the regular contour integral, it actually means the "average integral", $\frac{1}{|U|}\int_{U}\mathbf{u}dx=$ average of $\mathbf{u}$ over $U$. It's normally written as a regular integral sign with a slash through it, but I don't know the tag for it.)

Here is their proof:

Since $f$ is convex, for each $p \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that

$f(q) \geq f(p)+r\cdot (q-p)$ for all $q \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Let $p=\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy$, $q=\mathbf{u}(x)$:

$f(\mathbf{u}(x))\geq f\left(\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy\right)+r\cdot \left(\mathbf{u}(x)-\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy\right)$.

Integrate with respect to $x$ over $U$. $\square$

So, here's what I've done:

$f(\mathbf{u}(x))\geq f\left(\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy\right)+r\cdot \left(\mathbf{u}(x)-\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy\right) \to \\
f(\mathbf{u}(x)) \geq f\left(\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy\right)+r\mathbf{u}(x)-r\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy \to \\
\oint_{U}f(\mathbf{u}(x))dx \geq \oint_{U}\left[f\left(\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy\right)\right]dx + r\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}(x)dx - r\oint_{U}\left(\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dy\right)dx$.

Now, could someone help me figure out how to make the right side turn into $f\left(\oint_{U}\mathbf{u}dx\right)$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to note that

$$\oint_U \mathbf{u}\,dx$$

is a constant, and since you divide by the measure of $U$ for the average, you have

$$\oint_U c\,dx = c$$

for any constant $c$. So

$$\begin{align}
\oint_U\underbrace{f\left(\oint_U \mathbf{u}\,dy\right)}_{c = f(p)}\,dx &= f\left(\oint_U \mathbf{u}\,dy\right) = f(p),\\
\oint_U \underbrace{\left(\oint_U \mathbf{u}\,dy\right)}_p\,dx &= p,
\end{align}$$

and your right hand side simplifies to

$$f(p) + r\cdot p - r\cdot p = f(p) = f\left(\oint_U \mathbf{u}\,dx\right),$$

as desired.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel!! That was very helpful!